# Trouble replacing string with new values from a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

I am trying to replace characters from a `raw_input` `string` in the following manner:

```
descriptionsearch - raw_input('text')

def replace(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

replc = {' ': '', 'or': '=', 'and': '==', ',': '=', '+': '=='}

replace(descriptionsearch, replc)
print descriptionsearch
```

Currently when I `raw_input` "cat or dog" it returns the exact same "cat or dog".

I am not sure why this code is not working: I would greatly appreciate either an explanation of how to fix the code I am currently using or a more efficient manner of replacing terms from `raw_input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python and your `replace` function does not work in-place, but returns a new string. So you need to reassign the result:

```
descriptionsearch = replace(descriptionsearch, replc)
print descriptionsearch
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This solution worked well for me.  Stack overflow will not let me select this as the answer for another 11 minutes but the moment it will I will select this.  Thank you very much.